# sending image file in C

Tags: c, sockets, send, fopen, fread

I use this code to send binary file for my little HTTP server

```
/* send binary data to client */

void send_binary(int sock_fd, char *file_name)
{

    int buff_size = 10240;
    char buff[buff_size];
    long file_size;
    FILE *pFile;
    size_t result;
    if ( (pFile = fopen(file_name, "rb")) == NULL){
        error("fopen error\n");
    }

    while( (result = fread(buff, 1, buff_size, pFile)) == buff_size){
        send(sock_fd, buff, buff_size, 0);
        buff[0] = '\0';
    }
    if (result > 0){
        if(feof(pFile)){
            send(sock_fd, buff, result, 0);
        }
        else{
            error("read error\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);

}
```

It works for text, but not for jpeg files. The received image file is corrupted.

Comment: post the receive code...binary data can contain zeros....How are you determining length of data received?

Comment: It might be better to first send the size of the JPEG file and then the actual data.

Answer (score 6):

`fread` isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer on every read, so you should only `send` the number of bytes `fread` gave you. You're probably breaking out of the loop early when `fread` doesn't get you a full buffer. Try something like:

```
while (( result = fread( buff, 1, buff_size, p_file )) > 0 ) {
    send( sock_fd, buff, result, 0 );
}
```